Why can't Linux provide lighter/green threads?
I often hear that linux threads are heavy (requiring 8mb stack size) and this is why languages like golang implement their own green threads in userspace (allocating to the heap). This then allows handling say 100k connections instead of 10k connections. As I understand it, one problem with this is interop with C, and that this is why Rust moved away from them and went with async/await.
But if green threads are so popular, why can't Linux provide its own extremely light weight threads? In other words, why does every language needs to have its own complex thread scheduler ontop of the OS scheduler, when the OS seems better placed to make these scheduling decisions?

What makes you think Linux can't provide them?

I suppose the question could be rephrased as "Why doesn't Linux provide them?"


I often hear that linux threads are heavy (requiring 8mb stack size)

Can see where that claim comes from: A system (posix) thread's size depends on how you configure the task allocator. The default on modern 64 bit systems is indeed 8 MB, because that size kind of makes sense. Usually it grows far less, and I'm not even sure you'd have to actually allocate that memory unless you actually hit all these pages – just as with any other piece of virtual memory address space: If you don't use it, there's no physical memory backing.
Also, this is totally configurable, so if a program uses more, that's up to the programmer, not a systematic issue.

their own green threads in userspace (allocating to the heap).

I hear a lot of grandiose things about Go that turn out to be questionable (or wrong); this is among these. Doing your own stack management is of course possible – after all, libpthread doesn't do any magic – but the same stack amount will use the same amount memory. "allocating a stack on the heap" is an oxymoron; again, these are just regular virtual memory spaces, and the kernel positively doesn't care what you do in your own process' memory space.
If anything about what Go does differently than software that uses pthreads (and not all multi-threaded software does!) is "greener", then they might be reusing stack pages of short-lived threads; and libpthread to the best of my knowledge does the same. Again, after all, nothing here is magic.

This then allows handling say 100k connections instead of 10k connections.

"instead of 10k": [[quotation needed]]. I can write a bad server in an established language and then write a somewhat better server in my language of choice and come to the conclusion that my "favourite one" is faster, too.
I'll note that modern network servers are still by and large not written in Go, and if you really go all the way down to dataplane application servers, where you not only do the thread handling in your own process but also the network buffer management, Go has largely proven to be unpopular.
I'll give Go that the channel and short-lived workers are a nice concept, that languages like Erlang do properly.

that this is why Rust moved away from them and went with async/await.

err, Rust's std::thread's usage patterns proves this to be a false statement.

But if green threads are so popular, why can't Linux provide its own extremely light weight threads?

Because it does; Go uses Linux threads, so they can't be any heavier themselves than what Go does. How else would Go be able to have multiple threads than if the operating system continued executing the code that was running when it yielded? Any real go thread is a Linux thread; anything that is concurrent but doesn't get its own thread runs in a separate Linux thread, which comes from something that constitutes a thread pool or similar. This is by no means a Go feature or invention – thread pools and concurrency, futures and closures have been around roughly forever.

Getting a thread from a thread pool allows you to multiplex 100k things onto a much smaller number of other things. The normal terms (at least in the circles I move in)  for the first kind of thing is a "green thread" and for the second kind of thing is an "os thread" or just "thread. This does allow them to be lighter weight. As an analogy think cars and drivers and a car transporter. If the transporter only is moving one car then you have not saved any drivers, but if it is moving 12 cars then you have saved 11. Go doesn't claim to have invented things, it helped make them easier to use.

@icarus you saved 12 drivers ... the truck and 12 cars would require 13 drivers if driven separately

@icarus it stands to reason that different people would find different ways of constructing thread pools easier or harder, yes. Personally, I don't like Go's way of doing that, and you can build thread pools with C libraries quite effectively, though I'm mostly a C++ programmer when it comes to multi-threaded applications, so the magic there is either relying on C++ standard libraries parallel execution policy specifiers, or knowing how to avoid lock contention on the interface of jobqueues. I'd like to stress my answer's last paragraph: you don't have to reflect your model of concurrent…

… threads 1:1 with Linux threads (and it's usually a good idea to avoid doing short computations in a thread that you spawned for that solely!). The place where you'd want to have one Linux thread per your execution thread is if you have many parallel tasks that can be blocked externally – i.e., on syscalls (or, equivalently, accessing mmap'ed memory that boils down to a context switch); otherwise, when Linux returns control to your program, you'd need to figure out which point to continue at, which comes with its own overhead.

Thanks for the reply. I didn't intend to evangelize the merits of Golang or Erlang green threads, or Rust async/await. But given that these languages provide this by implementing their own schedulers on top of the scheduler in Linux, I wondered if it would make sense for Linux to provide this natively? I agree that much of the "heaviness" of threads can be ameliorated using pools. I'm not very knowledgeable about Linux, but I suppose the feature of Golang where you can essentially spawn a very quick closure callback would necessarily be too heavy to handle for Linux if it involves a syscall?
